# How to use jolokia to retrieve mbean for a class

Tags: java, logging, jmx, jolokia

I have a mbean for a class say foo.bar.Log4j
and I want to use jolokia to list all loggers?

I have tried reading on https://jolokia.org/reference/pdf/jolokia-reference.pdf but that tells me how to get values of predefined java.memory etc

Please suggest on how to get jolokia to retrieve loggers for a user-defined class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that even if your mbean is a singleton in your servlet, your servlet could be running on multiple endpoints - that's why the namespace alone is not sufficient to identify your mbean instance.

If you want to get all instances of `foo.bar.Log4j`, you can use the `read` endpoint like this:

```
http://yourserver/jolokia/read/foo.bar.Log4j:*
```

In general, you can get a list of all your available mbeans like this:

```
http://yourserver/jolokia/list
```

You should end up with a large json document that contains everything you might want to fetch. You will see things like

```
"foo.bar.Log4j": {
  "name=foo,type=MyLogger": {
    "desc": ...
    "attr": {
        ...
}}}
```

You can now get the attributes using something like this:

```
http://yourserver/jolokia/read/foo.bar.Log4j:type=name=foo,type=MyLogger
```

In addition to `type` and `name`, you may see other fields as well, for example `context` or `id`. This a:b key is the Java [ObjectName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/ObjectName.html) for your mbean.